# Using a configuration of YAML which is tab indented

Tags: python, yaml

I was writing a unit test, and I discovered a tool that writes YAML configuration with tab indention, but when I tried to read it using `yaml.load(file_object)` I get an error saying:

```
(<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 2 column 1
```

or with the tool I see in terminal:

```
while scanning for the next token
found character '\t' that cannot start any token
  in "/user/config/settings", line 2, column 1
```

Comment: Tab indentation is not allowed in YAML (see [6.1 Indentation Spaces](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2777534) in the specification: "To maintain portability, tab characters must not be used in indentation, since different systems treat tabs differently"). What is exactly your question?

Comment: well I read through documentation of yaml and it didnt say it allows tab, however I came across a PyQT UI tool that is writing yaml file tab intended and my code trying to check the user configuration getting the error above. You have answered my question , however was this ever supported to have tab in some old yaml versions ?

Comment: That is surprising, I'd say that is an error in the tool and could be reported. It seems tab indentation has been disallowed [since the oldest historical version of the specification](https://yaml.org/spec/history/2003-09-01.html#syntax-indent). Standard YAML libraries do this correctly, so I imagine it is a bad custom YAML generation. I think many cases (not sure if all) could be "fixed" by replacing initial tabs with a fixed number of spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although tab characters are valid in YAML, they cannot be used in
indentation, in neither the current version
([1.2](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2777534), nor in the
older [1.1](https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id891751), or
[1.0](https://yaml.org/spec/1.0/#id2560933))

That does **not** imply a tab cannot occur at the start of line, as the following
example shows

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
'xxx
\tyyy'
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.explicit_start = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print(data)
```

which runs without error and gives:

```
xxx yyy
```

if you remove the single quotes from the `yaml_str`, you will however
get the error that you got (on line 2, column 1), because the parser
has to consider if yyy starts a new token (while scanning the single
quoted scalar it doesn't do that).

Without seeing the actual YAML, it is difficult to say defitively, but
probalby your tool is to blame. You might get away with replacing the
tabs:

```
with open('yourfile.yaml') as fp:
    data = yaml.load(fp.read().replace('\t', ' '))
```