# load some of yaml in python

Tags: python, config, pyyaml

I only need to load some information from my yaml file in a dictionary.

I am using pyyaml's load function but that works on entirety of yaml file but I need something that will only load some of it.

Yaml file structure:

```
default:
    a : asasd
    b: asdads
node1:
    a1: asdsad
    b1: asdasda
node2:
    a1: sadads
    b1: asdsadads
```

I only need to load default and node1 in a dictionary and don't need node2 at all. (node1 and node2 have same keys but different values)
R lets me do it with config library as:

```
con = config::get(file,node)
```

Is there a way to do this in python?

---

My main issue is there is a tab character in one of the node (and I need no information from that node), and if I can just escape it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split yaml file into several files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43051295/how-to-split-yaml-file-into-several-files)

Answer (score 0):

You can load the whole file, and then select the nodes you need:

```
import yaml
with open("file.yaml", 'r', encoding='utf8') as stream:
    content = yaml.safe_load(stream)
default = content['default']
node1 = content['node1']
```

That is, unless file size is an issue.

Comment: the issue is the yaml file has a tab character in one of the node, which I don't need. So i am trying to see if i can escape it!

Comment: Assuming you can't avoid the malformed YAML, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55161009/using-a-configuration-of-yaml-which-is-tab-indented/55163394#55163394